# How many ways to get a 5 card hand with atleast 3 black cards

Tags: combinatorics

I've been given not a problem, but a claim and a "proof" that I have to find a problem in.
The claim is that in a 52 deck of cards, the number of ways to select a 5 hand card with at least 3 black cards is ${26 \choose 3} \cdot {49 \choose 2}$

The "proof" is that they are selecting three cards from 26 black ones, and then picking 2 from the remaining 49 (23 black cards + 26 red cards)
Now, I know that this is wrong and that they are over-counting, but I don't understand what they are overcounting. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're double counting because the hands with $4$ (or more) black cards are counted in more than way: say we have a hand with the black cards $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$. We could have selected $b_1,b_2,b_3$ among the $\binom{26}{3}$ group and $b_4$ among the "remaining cards" or $b_1,b_2,b4$ as the group of $3$ and $b_3$ as one of the remaining etc. So that hand is arrived at in at least two different ways in this counting scheme of "$3$ plus remaining". In fact we count it four times, this way, and a hand with $5$ black cards is even counted $10$ times.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great explanation.

Comment: @JosephKatrinka Glad you liked it..

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, since you will either have 3 or more black cards or 3 or more red cards, the answer has to be $(1/2) \times \binom{52}{5}.$

In answer to your specific question, consider the hand
$A,2,3,4,5$, all spades.  As far as overcounting goes, if you select the $A,2,3$ as your first 3 black cards, then you might also select the $4,5$ as the two *leftover* cards.

So, this particular combination of cards will be counted $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ times, rather than just once.

Answer (score 0):

You are double counting the black cards.

A simpler example may help: Let there be 4 balls called 1W,2W,1B,2B. From these you have to select atleast 2 black balls. You type of calculation yields- pick 1 black from the two in $\binom{2}{1}$, and any of the remaining in $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to yield a total of $\binom{2}{1}\times\binom{3}{1}=6$.

The correct answer would be to choose either 1 black amongst the two in  $\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}$ ways and 2 blacks in $\binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{0}$ ways for a total of $\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{0} = 4+1=5$ ways.

What have we double counted? The case of $\{1B,2B\}$. This is because, in the first calculation, for each black chosen in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways, you may still choose 1 additional black. Thus $\{1B,2B\}$ is counted different from $\{2B,1B\}$.

Similarly, in the case of the 5 card hand, you are counting these multiple times.